# Problem determining the bit length of a key from the modulus in the RSA algorithm

Tags: cryptography, integer, rsa

Here are two 64-bit (signed) integers

```
p = 13776308150928489016
q = 16488138731131959619
```

and their product

```
n = 112488352363349635896748360565917156710
```

The bit-length of the product is `floor ((log2 n) + 1)` or **127**.

Now here are another two 64-bit integers

```
p = 13275629912622491628
q = 16290498985329101221
```

and their product

```
n = 179030914337714357408535416678431567970
```

but this time the bit length is `floor ((log2 n) + 1)` or **128**.

The reason is that there's a leading zero in the first integer, which makes the space needed to represent the integer in memory one bit smaller.

The problem this causes is that I can't determine the bit length of the keys accurately. For example, here are is a very short RSA key pair:

```
Public key  : 7, 8371846783263706079
Private key : 2989945277626202443, 8371846783263706079
```

The modulus (8371846783263706079) is 63 bits, which the number I'm after is 64. The overcome this issue I have considered the following solutions:

1. Round up to the nearest 2^n
2. Store the key size in bits along with the key
3. Add some kind of padding to ensure all integers take up the same space (not sure how this would work in practice)

Which one is the correct solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you want a 64-bit modulus, then why not just choose values of *p* and *q* that give you a 64-bit modulus? Also, your calculations of *n* are both incorrect.

Comment: Because the guides on key generation that I'm following simply say that p and q should be half of the bit length of the key, i.e. 2^(n - 1) to 2^n - 1. Of course I could make p and q above a certain threshold to ensure n is always 64 bits, but that's not what I'm seeing in tutorials.

What error is in the calculations of n?

Comment: @r3mainer Hey I replied to your comment but forgot to quote you. Can you tell me where the error in the calculation of n is?

Comment: Well this is basic maths, but the product of two numbers is what you get when you multiply them together. If you multiply p and q in your examples, you don't get the values of n that you mentioned. In fact, both (p,q) pairs have [128-bit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13776308150928489016+*+16488138731131959619) [products](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=13275629912622491628+*+16290498985329101221). Also p and q are supposed to be *prime* numbers. All the examples you provided are *composite*. I suggest you look for a better tutorial on RSA.

Comment: @r3mainer Oh that's just a mistake I made copy pasting from the calculator... p and q weren't supposed to be prime numbers, I just picked them to illustrate the problem. Anyway I got the answer from another website, which was to use hex to make sure key sizes are padded to correct length, which is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @r3mainer notes, the math needed here -- [inequalities](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/inequality-solving.html) -- is not exotic. As to what tutorials say, well, they're just tutorials, they're trying to simplify as much as possible so they leave out some details.

What you are observing is the following:

you want two primes, p and q, to have the same bit length k and their product N to have a bit length of 2k.

By the definition of what it means to have a bit length of k, we have the following inequality:

1) 2<sup>(k-1)</sup> <= p, q < 2<sup>k</sup>.

However, when we multiply p and q we discover a problem:

2) 2<sup>(2k - 2)</sup> <= N < 2<sup>2k</sup>

This means that N=p*q may end up having bit length of 2k-1 or 2k, but we don't want 2k-1.

In your example k=64.

To fix it, we need to tighten up the lower bound on p and q to the following:

3) sqrt(2<sup>(2k-1)</sup>) <= p, q < 2<sup>k</sup>.

Bearing in mind that all results are integers, we apply the ceiling function and get finally

4) ceiling(sqrt(2<sup>(2k-1)</sup>)) <= p, q < 2<sup>k</sup>.

For k=64 this works out to:

13043817825332782213 <= p, q < 2<sup>64</sup>

An even simpler formulation is make the bounds dynamic, as in the following:

first find p, of any size. Then we want

2<sup>(2k - 1)</sup> <= p*q < 2<sup>2k</sup>, so

5) (2<sup>(2k - 1)</sup>)/ p <= q < (2<sup>2k</sup>)/p will do the trick.

For RSA, we actually do want both  primes to be sufficiently large and entropic, and yet not be too close to each other. We can do that by choosing p to have length k-1 or k-2 and applying 5).

Comment: Hey this is a good explanation for deriving the lower bound. I decided to use another method for solving the problem but this works just as well so marking as correct.